# How can I get group by with totalcost in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle.
One named `orders_new` is a table containing the names of products included in the order for the date:

```sql
+----------+---------------------+-----------+
| ORDER_ID |  PRODUCTSPURCHASED  | ORDERDATE |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+
|     1001 | rice,sugar,facewash | 20-AUG-20 |
|     1002 | sanitizer,handwash  | 21-JUL-20 |
|     1003 | dal                 | 01-MAY-20 |
|     1004 | facewash,handwash   | 22-AUG-20 |
|     1005 | sugar,facemask      | 0         |
+----------+---------------------+-----------+
```

and aslo I have other table named `products_new` - prices for products by month:

```sql
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| PRODUCTNAME | PRODUCTPRICE | MONTH |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| rice        |          100 | jul   |
| rice        |          110 | aug   |
| sugar       |           40 | feb   |
| sugar       |           50 | apr   |
| sugar       |           60 | aug   |
| facewash    |          110 | jul   |
| facewash    |          100 | aug   |
| sanitizer   |          200 | jul   |
| sanitizer   |          190 | aug   |
| handwash    |           50 | jul   |
| handwash    |          100 | aug   |
| dal         |           40 | may   |
| dal         |           45 | jun   |
| dal         |           50 | jul   |
| dal         |           55 | aug   |
| facemask    |           15 | feb   |
| facemask    |           20 | jul   |
| facemask    |           25 | aug   |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

I want output table as groupping by `order_id` with `totalcost`.
How can I get it?

Comment: Are you really storing `products_new(months)` as 3 characters, or you have a real `date` datatype?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, but you could try this one:

```
SELECT order_id, sum(productprice) AS totalcost
FROM products_new 
LEFT JOIN orders_new 
ON productname IN productspurchased AND month = DATEPART(month, orderdate)
GROUP BY order_id
```

Though the month should probably be stored as a type of DATE, too.
Not sure if it works like this.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your data model!  Storing multiple values in a single column is a bad, bad, bad idea.

But sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad, bad data models.  If this is the case, you can use logic like this:

```
select o.order_id, sum(p.price)
from orders_new o left jion
     products_new p
     on ',' || replace(o.PRODUCTSPURCHASED, ', ', ',') || ',' like '%,' || p.productname || ',%'
```

Note that this addresses both the problem of having separators and the fact that the separators are inconsistent (both commas and comma-space).

However, you should put your efforts into fixing the data model, by having a junction/association table with one row per order/product combination.

```
group by o.order_id;
```